# Where to set language for a project or model in EA?

Tags: enterprise-architect, appsettings

Is there a way to set the language for a model or for the whole project?

1. A setting so when I create a new class/element the language for that is automatcially set.
2. And can I change the language for all existing classes/elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can set the default language via `Project|Settings|Project Options...'
   [image]
2. There's no option to change it for all classes. You could create a little script, or change it in the database directly. Each model is actually stored in a database. Either a .eap file (MS-Access format) or a proper DBMS such as SQL-Server, MySQL,Oracle,... If you know your way around the database schema you can update your model directly int he database. 
   WARNING **Use this method only if you know what you're doing**

Comment: Thanks! Okay, it's on a project level which is probably sufficient in most cases. What do you mean with 'in the database directly'?

Comment: @robsch added an explanation about "in the database directly" in my answer.

Comment: And selecting multiple elements and change the property is an further option? I've got this impression with classes on a diagram, however, this did not always work (did not work with selecting all classes on the diagram, but when selecting e.g. two).

Comment: @robsch No, that doesn't work. The property is also not available in the list view, so it's either one by one, or using a script, or updating the database. Or another alternative is to export to xmi, change the language property in the xmi file and import again.

Comment: I see Language in the properties pane. But it seems if I select multiple elements on the diagram and change the property only a single item gets changed. Hm... multi-select yes, but multi-edit no.

Comment: @robsch You just found one of those nice places that makes EA's user interface "unique" ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian I was just about to buy it. Bad idea? Which alternatives do I have for 200$?

Comment: There is no alternative, unfortunately. EA is the one-eyed amongst the blind. It's price/performance ratio is unbeatable. You somehow get used to this "unique" UI.  (got the wrong input field...)

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the language for a whole project in one go, but you can change the language for everything within one root node in the project browser. So as long as you don't have a thousand of those (in fact, many people use just one) it's very easy to achieve.

Please see [my old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457076/enterprise-architect-project-programming-language/11473111#11473111).